# How can I manually set a field in Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to set some field data for Google Analytics tracker manually in a certain situation. In my JS I have the following:

```js
ga(function(tracker) {
   tracker.set('campaignKeyword', 'my keyword');
   tracker.send('event');
});
```

But I can't seem to see anything come through in Analytics.

I've run `console.log(tracker)` and it's a valid Universal Analytics tracking object — I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been referencing [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference).

What am I missing?

Comment: that documentation has the code `ga('send', 'event', {
  'eventCategory': 'Category',
  'eventAction': 'Action'
});` for sending an event.  I don't see anywhere in there where `tracker.send('event');` is supposed to do anything.  I also shows the example of `ga('set', 'campaignKeyword', 'Blue Shoes');` for setting the campaignKeyword.    Where did you get the code you are using?

Comment: Looks like legacy ga.js code. However even if sending an event for legacy code.. still needs event category and event action at the very least.. they are required

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```js
ga(function(tracker) {
  tracker.set('campaignKeyword', 'my keyword');
  tracker.set('eventCategory', 'my category');
  tracker.set('eventAction', 'my action');
  tracker.send('event');
});
```

Now you see the hit on Google Analytics, although this code is pretty ugly and not recommended by Google. :)  Lets improve it:

```js
ga('send', 'event', {
  eventCategory: 'my category', // required
  eventAction: 'my action',     // required
  campaignKeyword: 'my keyword' // optional
});

// or equivalent
ga('send', 'event', 'my category', 'my action', {
  campaignKeyword: 'my keyword'
});
```

The *eventCategory* and *eventAction* fields are required. If you don't pass them, you see the hit going on the browser's devtools network tab, but it will not be collected by GA servers.

Note: the previous commands only work if you have a tracker already created and named "t0", which is the default tracker. So, before those commands you must have something similar to `ga("create", "<your-property-id", "auto")`.

You can use also the excelent Chrome extension named "[Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)", that print (to the console) debug information about your `ga` commands.